# Is there any closed form solution for the following SDE?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

How can I solve the following SDE:

\begin{cases}
dX_{t}=-\sin X_{t}\cdot\cos^{3}X_{t}dt+\cos^{2}X_{t}dB_{t}\\
X_{0}=x_{0}
\end{cases}?

This SDE has the form of

$$dX_{t}=\frac{1}{2}\sigma'\left(X_{t}\right)\sigma\left(X_{t}\right)dt+\sigma\left(X_{t}\right)dB_{t},$$
and in this case, as far as I know there is a trick to use the Itô-formula
for the $h\left(X_{t}\right)$ function where $h\left(x\right)=\int\frac{1}{\sigma\left(x\right)}dx.$
So in this example $h\left(x\right)=\tan x$. Using the Itô-formula
for $h\left(X_{t}\right)$ we get the following:
\begin{align*}
h\left(X_{T}\right)-h\left(X_{0}\right)= & \tan X_{T}-\tan X_{0}\\
= & \int_{0}^{T}\frac{1}{\cos^{2}X_{t}}\left(-1\right)\sin X_{t}\cdot\cos^{3}X_{t}dt+\int_{0}^{T}\frac{1}{\cos^{2}X_{t}}\cos^{2}X_{t}dB_{t}+\int_{0}^{T}\tan X_{t}\cdot\cos^{4}X_{t}dt=\\
= & \int_{0}^{T}-\sin X_{t}\cos X_{t}+\sin X_{t}\cos^{3}X_{t}dt+B_{T}=\\
= & -\int_{0}^{T}\sin^{3}X_{t}\cos X_{t}dt+B_{T}.
\end{align*}
Can I get somehow a closed formula for the solution? Did I go wrong
somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if $Y=h(X)$, then
$$
dY_t=h'(X_t)dX_t+\frac12h''(X_t)d\langle X\rangle_t
\\
=\frac12h'(X_t)σ'(X_t)σ(X_t)\,dt+h'σ(X_t)\,dB_t+\frac12h''(X_t)σ(X_t)^2\,dt
$$
which suggests to take $h'(X_t)σ'(X_t)+h''(X_t)σ(X_t)=0$ leading to the given form of $h$.

---

When applying the Ito formula, your last term does not have the required form $\frac12h''(X_t)σ(X_t)^2\,dt$, the first factor should be $-\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3x}$. There is no minus sign in the first term of the same expression.

Comment: You are right...I just couldn't divide two functions -.- ... so I made a mistake calculating the second derivate of h.